# First Item of RecyclerView is Missing

Tags: android, file, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity. I am creating a File which has some data when activity is created. All the files are properly created and data is correctly written.
Following is my code

```
public class MyRecordingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecordingsAdapter recordingsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Recording>  recordingArrayList;
    private File userRecordingFile;
    private static final String USER_MIX_DIR = "UserMix";
    private String lines[]=new String[]{};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_recordings);


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            try{
                userRecordingFile = new File(createRecordingFiles(), "Recording"+i+".txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(userRecordingFile);
                writer.append("DEF"+i+"\nHIJ "+i);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        recordingArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        readFiles();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lines[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lines[1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[0],lines[1]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[2],lines[3]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[4],lines[5]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[6],lines[7]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[8],lines[9]));

        recordingsAdapter=new RecordingsAdapter(recordingArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recordingsAdapter);
    }


    public  File createRecordingFiles() {

        File dirRoot = getExternalCacheDir();

        File workDir = new File(dirRoot, USER_MIX_DIR);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!workDir.exists()) {
            workDir.mkdirs();

            File recordingFile = new File(workDir, "Recording File ");
            try {
                recordingFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
        return workDir;
    }


    public void readFiles(){
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br=null;
        try {
            File dirRoot = getExternalCacheDir();
            File workDir = new File(dirRoot, USER_MIX_DIR);

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                File file = new File(workDir,"Recording"+i+".txt");

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                    lines=text.toString().split("\n");

                }
            }


            br.close() ;
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

The Toast which i have written correcly displays DEF0 and HIJ 0, but they are not displayed in the recyclerview. Following is screenshot of the screen

[image]

Following is my Adapter Class

```
public class RecordingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordingsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    public static final int TYPE_HEAD=0;
    public static final int TYPE_LIST=1;
    private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList;

    public RecordingsAdapter(ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList) {
        this.recordingArrayList = recordingArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder;

        if(viewType == TYPE_LIST){
            view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_my_recordings,parent,
                    false);
            recyclerViewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;

        }else if(viewType == TYPE_HEAD){
            view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.head_layout,parent,
                    false);
            recyclerViewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Recording recording;
        if(holder.view_type==TYPE_LIST){
            recording=recordingArrayList.get(position);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(recording.getImage_id());
            holder.typeTextView.setText(recording.getTitle());
            holder.dateTimeTextView.setText(recording.getDatetime());

        }else if (holder.view_type == TYPE_HEAD){
            holder.typeHeaderTextView.setText("TYPE");
            holder.titleHeaderTextView.setText("TITLE");
            holder.dateTimeHeaderTextView.setText("DATE/TIME");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recordingArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        }
        return TYPE_LIST;
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        int view_type;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView typeTextView,dateTimeTextView;
        TextView typeHeaderTextView,titleHeaderTextView,dateTimeHeaderTextView;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            if(viewType==TYPE_LIST){
                typeTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cell_recording_recording_name);
                imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cell_recordings);
                dateTimeTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cell_recording_date_time);
                view_type=1;
            }else if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD){
                typeHeaderTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_type_head_layout);
                titleHeaderTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_head_layout);
                dateTimeHeaderTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date_time_head_layout);
                view_type=0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

DEf0 and HIJ 0 are not displayed in the recyclerview. I am not able to understand why they are not displaying in my recyclerview. I have no errors in my log. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post your `RecordingsAdapter` class?

Comment: Please post the content of your `activity_my_recordings.xml` file

Comment: @DanailAlexiev I have added the Adapter part. Please have a look

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: you may not have use R.layout.head_layout properly or it has all views hidden

Comment: You are returning `TYPE_HEAD` at position 0 not  `TYPE_LIST`. That's why it is not showing `TYPE_LIST` at position 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it in wrong way....

You are adding five items in `recyclerview`, but consider first is header.

So this takes your first item as header, and you see other four items.

What you need to do is, pass dummy item as first item and then add your 5 items.

this way you can solve your problem.

You can try this way:

```
recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"", ""));
recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[0],lines[1]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[2],lines[3]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[4],lines[5]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[6],lines[7]));
        recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,lines[8],lines[9]));
```

or you can also do it as below:

**change Adapter code**

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recordingArrayList.size() + 1;
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Recording recording;
        if(holder.view_type==TYPE_LIST){
            recording=recordingArrayList.get(position - 1);
            ...

        }else if (holder.view_type == TYPE_HEAD){
            holder.typeHeaderTextView.setText("TYPE");
            holder.titleHeaderTextView.setText("TITLE");
            holder.dateTimeHeaderTextView.setText("DATE/TIME");
        }
    }
```

**but you need to verify for empty list in this way**

Comment: I got you. But what if, i cant pass first item as dummy item?

Comment: you're passing first item as dummy item, but i dont want to do that

Comment: @LalitJadhav Thanks. I am not adding first item as dummy,but i am changing my Adapter Code as you said and it works. Thanks alot for the help. Appreciate it

Comment: @abu Your welcome.. but please my name is LalitJadav not LalitJadhav

Answer (score 3):

Your recycler view might be hidden under the toolbar. Give a top margin of 56dp.

```
android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this your first position is set your Title.

**Use this**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return TYPE_LIST;
}
```

**Instead of this**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0){
        return TYPE_HEAD;
    }
    return TYPE_LIST;
}
```

Comment: My app crashed.

Comment: Post the log please.

Comment: This is not a good solution. If you use the position again it is useless to override the getItemViewType.

Comment: @iamgopal java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType' on a null object reference

Comment: @abu you can user return as TYPE_LIST check my edit ans.

Comment: @abu check this reference https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is that first I remove from the array any null value (since the first element could be null) and then I add null value again. That way I'm avoiding of duplicating null value. I don't use "if" or any adapter implemented methods so I made my app more efficient.
 My code is as follow:

```
myArray.remove(null); // here I remove any preview added null value as first (0 position) element
myArray.add(0, null); //now I add null as first element
//this way I am avoiding showing content with a null values
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The toast is displayed because your card is there, but it's hidden by the toolbar. You can add some margin to the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop:"?android:attr/actionBarSize" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to add Header without passing first blank data from activity, than you need to add blank entry at first position inside your Adapter like this.

Replace this code inside your Adapter:

```
          public RecordingsAdapter(ArrayList<Recording>  recordingArrayList) {

           this.recordingArrayList = recordingArrayList;
           this.recordingArrayList.add(0,null);

          }
```